# What is the number of $k$-sorted arrays on $n$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is a combinatorics problem inspired by exercise 2 in the [lecture note](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/28-lowerbounds.pdf) on computer algorithms.

We say that an array $A[1 \ldots n]$ is $k$-sorted if it can be divided into $k$ blocks, each of size $n/k$ (we assume that $n/k$ is an integer), such that the elements in each block are larger than the elements in earlier blocks and smaller than elements in later blocks. The elements within each block need not be sorted.

What is the number of $k$-sorted arrays on $n$ elements?

Answer (score 1):

For each $1\le i\le k$ the contents of the blocks $B_i$ would have to be some ordering of
$$
B_i=\left\{\frac{n(i-1)}{k}+1,\frac{n(i-1)}{k}+2,\ldots,\frac{ni}{k}\right\}
$$
and then each of these $k$ blocks have $\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)!$ distinct orderings. So there should be
$$
\left(\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)!\right)^k
$$
distinct $k$-sorted arrays on $n$ elements.

Comment: Sorry for withdrawing the "accept". I am confused: why is it not $\binom{n}{n/k,\ldots,n/k} = \frac{n!}{((n/k)!)^k}$?

Comment: Because there is only one choice for the set of numbers in each block, up to ordering. Consider any $3$-sort of $\{1,2,\ldots,9\}$, we would have to have the first bucket filled with some ordering of $\{1,2,3\}$ followed by some ordering of $\{4,5,6\}$ and finished with some ordering of $\{7,8,9\}$. Now suppose I try a $3$-sort with the first bucket with some ordering of $\{1,2,4\}$. We cannot place $3$ in either of the subsequent buckets and still have all the elements of our first bucket be smaller than the subsequent bucket that contains $3$.

Comment: Your proposed answer has two flaws: it allows for any $k$ numbers to be placed in the each bucket and it doesn't count permutations of the elements in each of the buckets as distinct.

Comment: Thanks. I am quite confused about this. Would you mind having a look at [this post](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/73772/lower-bound-for-k-sorting-an-array) on cs.stackexchange? It is about algorithm analysis. However, the computer science part can be abstracted away.

Comment: My answer tells you the number of $n$-element $k$-sorted lists. Your proposed answer is a lower bound on the number of $n$-element lists partitioned into $k$ buckets. All the $n$-element $k$-sorted lists are a subset of all partitioned lists.